# Why it's not ok for variables to be global but it's ok for functions?

Tags: python, function, variables, closures, global

I was writing some Python code and, as usual, I try to make my functions small and give them a clear name (although sometimes a little too long). I get to the point where there are no global variables and everything a function needs is passed to it.

But I thought, in this case, every function has access to any other function. Why not limit their access to other functions just like we limit the access to other variables.

I was thinking to use nested functions but that implies closures and that's even worse for my purpose.

I was also thinking about using objects and I think this is the point of OOP, although it'll be a little too much boilerplate in my case.

Has anyone got this problem on her/his mind and what's the solution.

Comment: It makes inferring the state of an application almost impossible to know and increases the amount of information you have to store in your head to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of everyone reading your code, grouping the functions into classes will help to mentally categorize them.  Using the class `self` parameter helps to organize the variables, too, by grouping them in a class.

You can limit their access with a [single leading underscore](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) at the beginning of the function name.

Comment: Yup, I guess this is what I wanted to hear. It's not just about mutability but also about the general structure of the code.

Answer (score 7):

It is not a good idea to have global *mutable* data, e.g. variables. The mutability is the key here. You can have constants and functions to your hearts content.

But as soon as you write functions that rely on globally mutable state it limits the reusability of your functions - they're always bound to that one shared state.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are discouraged because they make it hard to keep track of the state of the program. If I'm debugging a 1,000-line file, and somewhere in the middle of a function I see `some_well_named_flag = False`, I'm going to have a lot of hunting to do to see how else it affects what else in the program.

Functions don't have state. The places where they can modify the program are more or less limited to the parameters and return value.

If you're still concerned about controlling access to functions, there are other languages like Java or C++ that can help you do that. One convention with Python is to prefix functions that shouldn't be used outside of the class with an underscore, and then trust people not to call them from outside the class.